# How to query fast from nested relationships in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have these tables in my SQLAlchemy database:

`DSource` table:

```
class DSource(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'dsource'

    source_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    subjects= relationship("Subject")
```

`Subject` table:

```
class Subject(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'subject'

    subject_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    source_id=Column(Integer, ForeignKey("dsource.source_id"),nullable=False)
    sequences= relationship("DSequence")
```

`DSequence` table:

```
class DSequence(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'dsequence'

    sequence_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    subject_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("subject.subject_id"),nullable=False)
    frames= relationship("Frame")
```

and `Frame` table:

```
class Frame(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'frame'

    f_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    sequence_id=Column(Integer, ForeignKey("dsequence.sequence_id"),nullable=False)
    action_units=Column(String)
    expression=Column(String)
    pts3d=Column(String)
    pts2d=Column(String)
```

Now I want to write a query against `Frame` table that gives me all the frames with `source_id=2`. One way is to write a nested loop that retrieves all the `subjects` with `dsource=2`, then for each of these subjects it finds the sequences and then for each sequence it finds the corresponding frames.

```
fr=session.query(Frame,Subject,DSequence,DSource).filter(DSource.source_id==2).all()
```

But querying against database that has these nested relationship is really slow, because in the `Frame` table I have around 90,000 frames. 
is there any way that I can query much faster? I'm not sure if `joinedload` can help me for this problem.

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution, there is a really easy way to do the above query and it is very fast:

```
session.query(Frame).join(DSequence).join(Subject).join(DSource).filter(DSource.source_id==2).all()
```